# Designing resource permission priority for RESTful

Tags: rest, permissions, acl

This is not about having permission to make GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request on resource endpoint. This is about certain user having GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request permission on certain resource.

In our application, we called it Access Control List (ACL) with the following sqlalchemy schema

```
class ACL(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'acl'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    res_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    res_type = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    permission = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    is_allowed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    users = db.relationship("User", secondary=acl_users)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

This ACL has many to many relationship with users and many to one relationship with each resource. This ACL can be four things:

1. if res_id is not null and users are not an empty list, it's called **"Exact"** because it specifies particular user's permission on particular resource
2. if res_id is null and users are not an empty list, it's called **"Anything"** because it specifies particular user's permission on any resource
3. if res_id is not null and users are an empty list, it's called **"Anyone"** because it specifies any user's permission on particular resource
4. if res_id is null and users are an empty list, it's called **"Any"** because it specifies any user's permission on any resource

I'm not sure this design is common or not, but it seems to have everything it needs to define resource permission.

The question is the following:

**If a resource has multiple ACLs, what should be the priority?**

We are down to three options:

1. Add 'priority' column on ACL table and let that determine priority. This approach makes sense but it becomes a nightmare to create Fetch Collection query that considers ACL by priority.
2. False >> True. e.g. "Anyone" False trumps "Exact" True. If "Anyone" is set False, no user has permission on the resource. This is easiest to make Fetch Collection query.
3. Exact >> Anyone >> Anything >> Any. Even if "Anyone" is False, if Exact user is set to be True, then all but that user has permission. Making Fetch Collection query is neither easy nor impossible.

Which one of these three options best reflect common practice on permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that any of those is common, the pattern in general is a little different from how I've seen permissions done in the past. (Incidentally, I found this post while looking up how other people have done permissions for a problem of my own, so thanks for the different perspective!)

My previous systems follow a pretty standard Roles+Permissions+Users system. (Many)Users can be assigned to (Many)Roles.  (Many)Roles can have a (One)Parent Role. (Many)Roles and (Many)Users can be assigned (Many)Permissions.  Permissions are either Allow or Deny and the Operation or Resource that is being controlled. We also had a "Neutral" permission but it isn't really necessary and tends to make an already complex system much worse.

The way I had structured that was that more specific permissions overrode less specific ones, so User trumps Role trumps ParentRole.  Within the same level, Deny trumps Allow. Unrelated Roles are the "same level", as are all permissions on any one object.  There are no separate priority controls to complicate things, the hierarchy of Roles bakes that in, and anything specific to a User is as narrow as it gets.

So to answer your question, I think you need to mix 2 and 3, or most likely just go with 3 since you wouldn't really have conflicting permissions on one level.  Exact permissions should always win. I would then say that Anything beats Anyone, as "Anything" is still specific to one subject, while "Anyone" is specific to a resource but not any particular user.  The Any is obviously least critical, acting essentially as a default.